# Is it unsafe to have some users with passwords and some without?

Tags: authentication, passwords, hash, password-policy

I'm working on an app where some accounts use passwordless authentication by email (using magic links) and some require a password to login. Is it okay to represent this rule in the account table by having a nullable password_digest? Would the application be more vulnerable to attack if and attacker knew which users have set a password and which ones haven't?

Comment: In my opinion there is only one correct answer to this question and it goes like this: Yes! It is unsafe.

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks, are you able to describe the vulnerability in more detail and prescribe a solution? Should I hash a randomly generated password for the password_digest on all accounts upon creation?

Comment: Having no password for user accounts is a design flaw. An attacker could attempt to send a large amount of usernames / email addresses without sending a password. Depending on the response of the application, the attacker could programmatically determine whether the username is correct or not. As far as the randomly generated passwords, I'd lock the accounts first, do a password reset by the user that was created and send an email to set a password using a temporarily generated link. If all is done successfully, unlock the account and it is ready for use.

Comment: Passwordless authentication via email? Like, there's only the email, or you are using magic links?

Comment: @ThoriumBR Using magic links. The user enters their email address and they receive an email with a one-time-use link.

Comment: I suggest you update the question with this information about magic links @CanadaIT

Comment: @Jeroen The business requirement we've received is that some accounts (client) must only login using magic links, while others (managers) require a password. What's the most secure way to fulfill this requirement?

Comment: Why not allow both password and magic link?

Comment: @ThoriumBR That's what I'm thinking, but I'm mostly concerned about the possible vulnerabilities of some users not having a hashed password in the database. At least if there's no password_digest for a user, an attacker would require access to that user's email account in order to login. Of course, the downside to this is that an attacker would know that they need to break into that email account. Is it really more secure to store a hash of a randomly generated password that the user doesn't know?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with this, as long as there is no way for the user to generate a null password digest when attempting to log in.

Otherwise, magic links are no less secure than the access offered by the password reset feature on most sites already. You could even argue that having no passwords is more secure, since there is no longer a secret that can become compromised (assuming the email account is better protected).

Comment: Would it be preferable to give every new user in the database a password digest generated from a random string, or give all new users a blank password digest? My theory is that the latter is a better option because it reduces the attack surface. An attacker could (again, theoretically) not gain access by breaking the password, their only option is to break into the user's email. Am I correct? To me this seems the same as any application with single factor authentication.

Comment: @CanadaIT well, a random digest may be guessable/brute-forceable, whereas a blank one is probably not forgeable.

Comment: @CanadaIT I'd say more code == more attack surface.  It also means more code to maintain.  As long as your password checking mechanism accounts for null passwords, which sounds pretty trivial.  Random password generation isn't always completely random depending on the mechanism you use, and I'd trust a null check if all else is equal.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a chat with your client regarding this "business requirement". The design does not look sound, if at least there was a good reason ? The problem is that you start with a flawed model, and then you wonder about the possible issues and try to find workarounds for the problems stemming from that design.

It shouldn't be like that. Keep it **simple** and secure - KISS. Don't make the job more difficult than it should be. Devise **one** common authentication scheme for all users, not two.

Technically speaking, there isn't much difference between the two. The 'passwordless' option is actually a token, so it's like a one-time password that has to be changed every time.

I am not in your shoes but if I am presented with unreasonable requirements I may very well walk away because I only do quality work and I don't want to endorse bad ideas.
Also, in case of a data breach, you could be held liable for the vulnerabilities in **your** code, if the implementation turns to be insecure. Not your idea, but your code.

Notwithstanding the possible security issues there are practical concerns too: an E-mail can be delayed, or never arrive because it was trapped as spam. Then the user is stuck. What a brilliant idea. I would reconsider it.

Security issues: I don't see any obvious issues ATM but the devil is in the implementation. Inevitably, this kind of design allows targeted DDOS: if you know the username/E-mail of someone, you can send automated requests for a token non-stop, and the user will not be able to login as a result. Thus, you've created an attack vector that didn't have to be there.